# Using REGEXEXTRACT in an array, searching multiple columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, re2

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in this formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT((A2:A&"")+(B2:B&"")+(C2:C&"")), "02(\d{14})37")
```

I'm trying to extract a 14 digit number that sits between 02 and 37 that may be in columnA, columnB or columnC.

I've tried this also, with the expected result showing on the first row only:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(textjoin(" ",true,A2:C),"02(\d{6,14})37"))
```

I'm really confuzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "02(\d{14})37"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B&"", "02(\d{14})37")),   
 REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C&"", "02(\d{14})37")))))
```

Comment: hoping you can take a look at this, following on from your above comment.... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lp5UdbYtkfOUd8qw0znRbUQUdG3rqvhGkfAvSzCeXzY/edit?usp=sharing - I'm having trouble with columns H-I and J-K. The dark yellow columns contain your suggestion above. But both yours and the original formula, are throwing up errors, or rather, not the result I was hoping for. I've added what i was expecting in cell A37 in order to keep this post to the point. Would really appreciate your help. Best regards, manc.

Comment: **`I1` cell:** `={"10 BATCH / LOT # - n2+an..20";ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(
REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "^15(.+)"), "10(.{6,10})"), 
REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B&"", "^15(.+)"), "10(.{6,10})")),   
REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C&"", "^15(.+)"), "10(.{6,10})")))), "^10", ))}`