# REGEXEXTRACT - Is it possible to have two captures

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Imagine a 100 digit number and in that number is 15 followed at some point by 10.

Is it possible to have two capture groups when using `REGEXEXTRACT` so I can tell it to lookup the 15 first, then when you reach 10, `REGEXEXTRACT` {6}, for example

Comment: You want the six digits immediately following 10, after 15 has appeared?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - yes sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(""&A2, "15(.+)"), "10(.{6})")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: But now the all all important how do i make this into an array formula over A2:A,B2:B,C2:C? I have tried =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(""&{A2:A,B2:B,C2:C}), 
 "15(.+)"),"10(.{10})")))))

Comment: same as this answer wrapped in 4 IFERROR functions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129095/5632629

Comment: I'm using =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT({A2:A,B2:B,C2:C}), 
 "02(\d{6,14})37"))),,999^99)))) for stackoverflow.com/a/57129095/5632629. Wondered if i could build it into the same?

Comment: Success: =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT({A2:A,B2:B,C2:C}), 
 "^15(.+)"), "10(.{10})"))),,999^99)))) - Thank-you for time player0 - really appreciated.

Comment: @manc_stu congrats, but you should note that in case the string can be extracted from both columns on the same row you will gain duplicate string appended together with this query smash approach. hence the recommended approach is that wich IFERRORs instead of the QUERY one.

Comment: Understood @player0. What you suggest could happen, and we need to avoid it. Thanks.